# Display Only the Product Add to Cart Button

Tags: 8, commerce

Drupal 8.4.2

On both the `commerce-product` and the `node--product` level, I can get the add to cart button to show, but it also renders the `product variation` fields as well.

If I have content that does not have variations and only a single price, how can I render just the "add to cart button" in the commerce form?

I've been all through config via the admin panel and feel I am just missing something obvious???

My question would be: How do you render just the add to cart button on the product level, or node level (via reference) via the admin panel?

Comment: Instead of writing "latest release of Drupal 8 as of date", please give the version number (8.4.2).  Writing it with the date will make your question harder to understand for readers as time passes.

Comment: Some notes that might be helpful: [Add to cart config is here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250504/where-is-the-add-to-cart-configuration), but it doesn't let you choose to show or hide the variations.  So I assume you have to theme the form, but [I haven't been able to figure out how to theme the add to cart form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250509/how-to-print-the-product-variation-separately-from-the-submit-pay-button-in-a-co).

Comment: Updated question with Drupal version. And I was wondering the same and I guess I will look more at theming the form... I'll post anything I may find, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the link above resolved my question: [Where is the "add to cart" configuration?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250504/where-is-the-add-to-cart-configuration).

There is a sub-menu link that I was missing.
[image]

This allowed me control of the display of the form items on both the product and node level. With this I am able to choose to show the variations and quantity fields. Thanks Patrick Kenny!